# Meet a Illegal Type conversion prolem in Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

```
    program ideone;
    const m = 7;
    const n = 5;
    var  x:Real;
    var  y:Real;
    var  z:Real;
    var  q:Real;
    var  r:Real;

    procedure  multiply();
    var a:Real;
    var b:Real;
    begin  a := x;  b := y;  z := 0;
      while b > 0 do
        begin  
          if odd(Qword(b)) then z := z + a;
          writeln('x');
          a := 2*a;  
          b := b/2;
        end
    end;

    begin 
      x := m;  y := n;  
      multiply();
      writeln(z);
    end.
```

Procedure “multiply” is used to calculate the product of two number.But it seems that a dead loop will appear and keep print "x" when the program is running.

Maybe it's because the type of "b" is "Real", so the line "b = b/2" can never cause the var "b" less than or equal to 0, while "b <= 0" is the exit of the loop.

So I change the type of b ti Integer hoping that b / 2 can cause b to 0 when b is Integer.

```
    program ideone;
    const m = 7;
    const n = 5;
    var  x:Integer;
    var  y:Integer;
    var  z:Integer;
    var  q:Integer;
    var  r:Integer;

    procedure  multiply();
    var a:Integer;
    var b:Integer;
    begin  a := x;  b := y;  z := 0;
      while b > 0 do
        begin  
          if odd(Qword(b)) then z := z + a;
          writeln('x');
          a := 2*a;  
          b := b/2;
        end
    end;

    begin 
      x := m;  y := n;  
      multiply();
      writeln(z);
    end.
```

Then I meet another problem:

```
test.pas(19,13) Error: Incompatible types: got "Extended" expected "SmallInt"
```

To solve this problem, I add a cast to line "b = b/2"

```
 b := Integer(b/2);
```

but another error occur:

```
test.pas(19,12) Error: Illegal type conversion: "Extended" to "SmallInt"
```

What should I do to solve this series problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem, you have to be aware that `Real` numbers are not precise, and when you work with them, you always have to use a `tolerance value` or mathematically `round` them.

```
const tolerance:Real = 0.001;
while b > tolerance do
```

or

```
while Round(b) > 0 do
```

For your cast problems, use `Round()` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It  help me. a new learner of pascal a lot  :-)

Comment: The division operator in Pascal is "div" not "/". I also don't understand the purpose of the call to Qword(b).

Comment: `div` is used to make integer divisions, while `/` uses the arithmetic unit.